# How to add the data from html tag on "Google Chart" arrayToDataTable? using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

**the td id='data' has the value below**

['car', 7],['jeep', 2],['taxi', 1]

**I want to get the value of 'td tag' and put on "Google Chart" arrayToDataTable**

*i tried this but not working*

> var ***x*** = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML; var data =
>   google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>             ['Data', 'Value'],
>            ***x***
>           ]);

Can anyone tell me how to do it....
need help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add brackets and make an array out of the string (innerHTML / innerTEXT) that you get from the TD and then add those rows.

Be sure the TD is inside TR and that is inside TABLE, or use a DIV instead of a TD

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Cartype');
data.addColumn('number', 'Amount');

//var tdString = "['car', 7],['jeep', 2],['taxi', 1]";
//var tdString = document.getElementById('data').textContent;
var tdString = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;

var arr = eval("[" + tdString + "]");

data.addRows(arr);
```

Anyway: working fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/L3tNE/15/

Comment: @4nti- **how to do it in this format below**                                                                                                                                                                                                                      var tdString = document.getElementById('data').innerHTML;               var arr = eval("[" + tdString + "]");                                                                                                            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
['Trips', 'Trip Value'],  ---->**arr**       ]); ----doesnt work

Comment: sir... can you please show me how to display the data from select tag "options value"....

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking but I assume you are searching for this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113495/javascript-get-list-of-all-values-in-select-box.  Please note that if these comments do not contribute to the original question it is better to ask a new question or ofcourse first search the website because I'm pretty sure you will find what you need if you do a little bit of searching here on stackoverflow.